# Emptiest custom theme as possible

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-2.1

For a professional project in Magento 2, my coworkers have to supply me a full static HTML integration. On the magento side, to make it easier, I want to start from the most empty theme and to stick as close to the HTML DOM they will create as possible.

But I'm not sure which way I can follow :

- Every topic I read on this subject suggest to start with a new custom theme which herite from the blank theme.
- Another way would be to create a custom theme which herite from no other theme, and create custom page layout (avoiding empty.xml to add some html), ...

Do you have some advices on these both ways ? I would need pros and cons to make the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion:

- Choose Nearest/Best Theme (Buy/Get Free for Marketplace) as per your requirement/need & Implement/Install
- Apply your HTML design changes on top of that

Pros

- It will save lots of time, rather than developing from scratch.
- You don't have to design each & every page.

Cons

- Maybe you have to pay to get your theme

Suggestions are welcome from Magentoians.